# How to show zero rows for non-existent values

Tags: mysql, join

I'm sorry if the title doesn't represent the question as I am not a native English speaker and I don't know how to name this situation. Title recommendation is appreciated.

I have the following query

```
SELECT mp.PerTPay,bz.BizCode,bz.BizName,count(*) PerCount FROM tb_perbiz bz
LEFT JOIN ms_per mp ON BizCode=mp.PerBiz
GROUP BY bz.BizCode,mp.PerTPay
ORDER BY bz.BizCode,mp.PerTPay
```

which produces the result

```
PerTPay  BizCode   BizName  PerCount 
1        01        AAAAA    2
1        02        BBBBB    9
1        03        CCCCC    66
2        03        CCCCC    83
1        04        DDDDD    57
2        04        DDDDD    103
```

but the following is the result I wanted. I want all possible PerTPay (both 1 and 2) to show for each BizCode.

```
PerTPay  BizCode   BizName  PerCount 
1        01        AAAAA    2
2        01        AAAAA    0
1        02        BBBBB    9
2        02        BBBBB    0
1        03        CCCCC    66
2        03        CCCCC    83
1        04        DDDDD    57
2        04        DDDDD    103
```

These are my tables

```
"ms_per"
PerCode    PerBiz    PerTPay
0001       01        1
0002       01        1
0003       02        1
0004       02        2
and so on

"tb_perbiz"
BizCode   BizName
01        AAAAA
02        BBBBB
03        CCCCC
04        DDDDD
```

I can't change the main table of the query to ms_per because the query I am showing is reduced from a very large one and it mostly depend on tb_perbiz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, to get a specific combination in your result, you need to generate that combination first. You can do this if you join your data with a table that contains all allowed values for `PerTPay` - which is actually the same basic idea why you are left joining to the `tb_perbiz`-table: a table that contains all allowed values for `BizCode`. This makes sure you get every code even if it does not exist in `ms_per`. Otherwise you could just group the table `ms_per` only.

Since you only have two values, you can generate that table dynamically:

```
SELECT pt.PerTPay, bz.BizCode, max(bz.BizName) as BizName, 
       count(mp.PerCode) PerCount 
FROM tb_perbiz bz
CROSS JOIN (select 1 as PerTPay union select 2) pt
LEFT JOIN ms_per mp ON bz.BizCode=mp.PerBiz and mp.PerTPay = pt.PerTPay
GROUP BY bz.BizCode,pt.PerTPay
ORDER BY bz.BizCode,pt.PerTPay;
```

The `cross join` will give you all possible combinations, wether they exist in `ms_per` or not.

Note that the grouping is now done on that new "table", and that I changed `count(*)` to `count(mp.PerCode)` to make sure to only count existing rows in `ms_per`. I also added an aggregate function to `BizName` (`max(bz.BizName)`), as it is not part of the `group by` (although I guess that `BizCode` is your primary key anyway).

Although I used a subquery here to generate the table dynamically, you may want to add an actual table (if you don't have such a table already e.g. to use it in a foreign key). It will e.g. allow you to simply add a `3` there, and your query and all similar queries would produce the expected new result without changing any query code.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and criticism on my query. With your code and some tweaks to my actual query it can show the results I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT mp.PerTPay,bz.BizCode,bz.BizName,count(mp.PerTPay) PerCount, count(mp2.PerTPay) PerCount2 FROM tb_perbiz bz
LEFT JOIN ms_per mp ON BizCode=mp.PerBiz AND mp.PerTPay = 1
LEFT JOIN ms_per mp2 ON BizCode=mp2.PerBiz AND mp2.PerTPay = 2
GROUP BY bz.BizCode,mp.PerTPay
ORDER BY bz.BizCode,mp.PerTPay
```

It won't give you precisely the row layout you presented, but it will give you the counts for PerTPay 1 and PerTPay 2 in separate columns - so essentially you are getting the same information but in slightly different format

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately the actual query have lots of sum columns, not just PerCount, and there are 8 more columns that use joins. And I have to make sure I can sum both of PerTPay for each BizCode in a reportbuilder. I will wait for other answers but if it is really impossible then I will have to use your method, which means writing 2X more code than 94 lines I already have.